# Word tokenization using python regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, string, tags

I am trying to split strings into lists of "tags" in python.  The splitting should handle strings such as "HappyBirthday" and remove most punctuation but preserve hyphens, and apostrophes. My starting point is:

```
tags = re.findall("([A-Z]{2,}(?=[A-Z]|$)|[A-Z][a-z]*)|\w+-\w+|[\w']+"
```

I would want to turn this sample data:

```
Jeff's dog is un-American SomeTimes! BUT NOTAlways
```

Into:

```
['Jeff's', 'dog', 'is', 'un-American', 'Some', 'Times', 'BUT', 'NOT', 'Always']
```

P.S. I am sorry my description isn't very good. I am not sure how to explain it, and have been mostly unsuccessful with google.  I hope the example illustrates it properly.

Edit: i think i needed to be more precise, so also,

1. if the word is hypenated and capital, like 'UN-American' will it keep it as one word so output would be  'UN-American'
2. if the hyphen has a space on either or both sides, a la 'THIS- is' or 'This - is' it should ignore the hypen and produce ["THIS", "is"] and ["This", "is"] respecticly,
3. and simmilarly for an apostrophe if its in the middle of a word like "What'sItCalled" it should produce ["What's","It", "Called"]

Comment: In general this is known as tokenization or "word tokenization" and there's no general solution to this problem. I'd be prepared to accept less-than-perfect solutions.

Comment: Another issue is that using regular expressions for something as complicated as word tokenization is likely to yield a relatively arcane solution.

Comment: Arcane or not, I don't care if I don't get it, if it works, l'll be happy.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I suggest the following:

```
re.findall("[A-Z]{2,}(?![a-z])|[A-Z][a-z]+(?=[A-Z])|[\'\w\-]+",s)
```

This yields for your example:

```
["Jeff's", 'dog', 'is', 'un-American', 'Some', 'Times', 'BUT', 'NOT', 'Always']
```

Explanation: The RegExp is made up of 3 alternatives:

1. `[A-Z]{2,}(?![a-z])` matches words with all letters capital
2. `[A-Z][a-z]+(?=[A-Z])` matches words with a first capital letter. The lookahead `(?=[A-Z])` stops the match before the next capital letter
3. `[\'\w\-]+` matches all the rest, i.e. words which may contain `'` and `-`.

Comment: so if the word is hypenated and capital, like 'UN-American' will it keep the - or remove it? what about for 'THIS-' or 'This-'? or even "What'sItCalled"

Comment: Also, if the '-' has spaces around it it should be removed, i.e. "this should - do that" ["this","should","do","that"]

Comment: @user779420: If you want to remove single hyphens, or more generally single letters, you could call `filter (lambda s: len(s)>1, ...)` to the string-list.

Comment: Will it matter then if that leaves 2 spaces side by side? also, can you link me to an explanation of that? im not familiar with it.

Answer (score 3):

To handle your edited cases, I'd modify phynfo (+1) great answer to

```
>>> s = """Jeff's UN-American Un-American un-American 
           SomeTimes! BUT NOTAlways This- THIS- 
           What'sItCalled someTimes"""
>>> re.findall("[A-Z\-\']{2,}(?![a-z])|[A-Z\-\'][a-z\-\']+(?=[A-Z])|[\'\w\-]+",s)
["Jeff's", 'UN-', 'American', 'Un-', 'American', 'un-American', 
 'Some', 'Times', 'BUT', 'NOT', 'Always', 'This-', 'THIS-', 
 "What's", 'It', 'Called' 'someTimes']
```

You have to clearly define the rules for your wanted behaviors.  Tokenization isn't a definition, you have to have something similar to phynfo's rules.  E.g., you have a rule that `'NOTAlways'` should go to `'NOT'`,  and `'Always'`, and that hyphens should be preserved.  Thus `'UN-American'` is split up, just like UNAmerican would be split up.  You can try defining an additional rules, but you have to be clear about which rule is applied when rules overlap.